# Getting Ajax requests from php file in a client node.js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, node.js

So I am trying to get an AJAX request to return a value to my node.js client side page.
It is communicating with a diffrent port so I am assuming this is causing the issue.

I have the following.

client.html file

```
socket.on('connect', function(){

    var user;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      } 
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        user=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","http:localhost:80/getUserSession.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    alert(user);

});
```

getUserSession.php file

```
<?php
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
 session_start();//start the session
 if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
   echo $_SESSION['username'];
 }

 ?>
```

If I directly run my `http:localhost:80/getUserSession.php` file it echos out the currentSession user. However when using the request it is alerting the value as undefined.
Thanks Shane

UPDATE
Hi thanks for the response I have checked the log files, firstly the ajax request does go to the log however I can see that it is going to localhost:8080 when it should be localhost:80

This is what is in the log when trying to execute the ajax request note the `localhost:8080` even tho I have `http://localhost:80/getUserSession.php` in the ajax request

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2014:23:02:33 +0000] "GET /getUserSession.php HTTP/1.1" 200 - "`http://localhost:8080/`" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

And this is the log when I manaully visit the link and see the echo'd username.

```
 127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2014:23:03:19 +0000] "GET /getUserSession.php HTTP/1.1" 200 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:27.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/27.0"
```

Comment: Does the AJAX request reach the server? Can you find it in the log files?

Comment: I don't understand: where is Node.js in all of this?

Comment: Thanks for the comments I have updated the original post

Answer (score 0):

If you want to echo a user name from your database, I wouldn't use your node.js file that you listed above.

Instead I would do a few things differently:

1) Create a regular index.html file containing an AJAX call to your 'getUserSession.php'
2) Create a 'Config.php' file that will link to your database with your desired values
3) Echo the current session user that is accessing your database.

The AJAX call:

```
 $.ajax(
{
    type: "GET",
    url: 'getUserSession.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    success: function (result) {
        $("#container").html(result); // '#Container' is a DIV that you will put in your index.html file...This is where the user name will be printed on your webpage.
    }

});
```

Config.php:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");     http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php 
define( "DB_DSN", "YOUR DATABASE HOST AND DATABASE NAME INFORMATION"); 
define( "DB_USERNAME", "YOUR USER NAME");
define( "DB_PASSWORD", "YOUR USER PASSWORD");
define("ADMIN_USERNAME", "YOUR ADMIN USER NAME");
define("ADMIN_PASSWORD", "YOUR ADMIN PASSWORD");

function handleException ( $exception) {
echo "Sorry, a problem occurred.  Please try later.";
error_log( $exception->getMessage() );
}

set_exception_handler('handleException');


?>
```

getUserSession.php:

```
<?php
require("config.php");
session_start();

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

echo DB_USERNAME;

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but still no joy, I am thinking its possibly a cross browser request issue between the different ports any ideas?